# How does this discord.js command violates if statement?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite, sequelize.js, discord.js

One of my commands is responsible for checking the date of one's assignment and then compare it with today's date. This command is supposed to work when the user's assignment's date is expired, e.g. the difference between months is 0 or less, and the difference between days is less than 2. Moreover, the person issuing the command is supposed to have KICK_MEMBERS permission.

However console.log() of values, which show difference in months (monthn) and days (daysn), is accurate, somehow the code violates if statement and passes it. In result, it outputs a `message.reply('issue')` instead of needed `` message.channel.send(`Я только что оповестил ${useralert.username}!`); ``.

Here's the code. Thanks in advance!

```js
else if (cmd == `${prefix}aalert`) {
            var i;
            var d = new Date;
            var month = d.getMonth() + 1;
            var day = d.getDate();
            const s = await Tags.count();
            if (message.member.hasPermission('KICK_MEMBERS')) {
                for(i=1;i<=s;i++) {
                    const tag = await Tags.findOne({ where: { key: i } });
                    if (tag) {
                        var date = tag.get('description');
                        let useralert = (tag.get("usernameid")).toString();
                        let useralertID = useralert.replace(/[<@>]/g, '');
                        let user = bot.users.cache.get('useralertID');
                        let deadday = parseInt(date.slice(0,2));
                        let deadmonth = parseInt(date.slice(3,5));
                        let dayn = deadday - day;
                        let monthn = deadmonth - month;
                        console.log(dayn.toString() + ' ' + monthn.toString() + ' ' + useralertID);
                        if(((dayn <= 2) && (monthn =0))|| (monthn < 0)) {
                            // user.send('Works!');
                            return message.channel.send(`Я только что оповестил ${useralert.username}!`);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return message.reply(' issue ');
    }
```

Comment: `monthn =0` is wrong; should be `monthn == 0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This statement is partly wrong

```
 if (((dayn <= 2) && (monthn =0))|| (monthn < 0))
```

because `monthn=0` is no comparison but an allocation.

Try it this way:

```
if(((dayn <= 2) && (monthn == 0))|| (monthn < 0))
```